# How can I delete files that are not ended with “.c” in a directory using shell script?

Tags: bash

I tried just like this

```
find -type f -name '*\.[^c]' -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -type f |grep -v '.*\.c' | xargs rm -f
```

seems they are not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try negating your name search using `!`.

```
find -type f ! -name '*\.c' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Good one! You will never walk alone :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this using delete command:

```
find -not -name "*.c" -type f -delete
```

Comment: `-not` is a `GNU`ism for `!`.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of a character is `!` not `^` with pattern matching.

```
-name '*.[!c]'
```

But that would not be correct since that would require any name to end in a dot and a single character other than `.`

If you are using a regular expression then you need to use an anchor ($):

```
grep -v '\.c$'
```

But using 'grep' and xargs that way will not work properly with file names with spaces or special characters..

So if you are trying to delete files in the current directory and all its sub directories try:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.c" -exec rm -f {} +
```